# Django development - Accessing results from a model

Tags: php, python, django, django-models, django-views

Once i have loaded my model and filtered it if i need to, how do i then access the results? I can find loads of examples on querying and filtering the model but none on how to work with the object thats returned?

My model looks like this...

```
class Ratecard(models.Model):
    region = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    reportSuite = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    RP_UniqueUsers = models.IntegerField()
    RP_PageImpressions = models.IntegerField()
def __str__(self):
    return self.region
```

and my simple index view is like this...

```
def index(request):

    reportSuites = Ratecard.objects.all()

    return render_to_response('index.html', locals())
```

What i want to be able to do is filter based on region and then access the values in the other fields... This is something very simple in PHP but i know hardly any python / django so any help would be amazing.

Right, so what i need to do is perform some calculations on what is returned, so i could do... `reportSuite = Ratecard.objects.get(region="Liverpool") answer = reportSuite.RP_UniqueUsers * 100`

Is that correct?

Comment: A model is a simple Python class.  Each instance of the model class is just an object.  What parts of accessing attributes of an object do you find confusing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to use instance, something like:

```
reportSuite = Ratecard.objects.get(id=??)
reportSuite.region

reportSuite = Ratecard.objects.all()
for reportSuite in reportSuites:
    reportSuite.region
```

But if you wish to use the instance(es) in your page directly, you must do it in the template

```
return render_to_response('template_name', {'reports':reportSuites})
```

In the template:

```
{%for report in reports%}
    {{report.region}}
{%endfor%}
```

Information about [render_to_rsponse](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response)
Info about [Django Templates](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/templates/)

UPDATE: yes, you can do it, but best place for such things are your view functions... So:

```
answer = reportSuite.RP_UniqueUsers * 100
return render_to_response('template_link', {'reports':reportSuites, 'ans':answer})
```

And in your tepmlate, you can use

```
{{ans}}
```

to show your result...

Comment: Right, so what i need to do is perform some calculations on what is returned, so i could do...

reportSuite = Ratecard.objects.get(region="Liverpool")
answer = reportSuite.RP_UniqueUsers * 100

Is that correct?

Comment: @Matthew: Please **update** your question with this kind of thing.  It's impossible to find in a comment.  And your question -- as written -- without this comment -- makes no sense.  Please **update** your question.